# php - how to hide the HTML part when no session_start();

Tags: php, html

thank you in advance , i wanted to stop not logged_in visiters from reaching some pages 
i know i can just do that  by cheking values in SESSION_ and  and showing the HTML part with

```
<?php  echo '<html>...</html>'; ?>
```

but i have a very long html content with  both  '' & "" text delimiters because it's not only HTML there is some JavaScripts, so i'm looking for another methode rather than printing the code with ECHO , and in this case i can't mixt PHP and HTML code . i there any solution or another idea to secure page from non member to see it,

and can i use this code to take them back to hope page (? :

```
 <?php  header("Refresh: 0;url=http://index.php/");  ?>
```

is it secure ?

Comment: You can use `include $file;` instead of `echo 'code'`

Answer (score 0):

> so i'm looking for another methode rather than printing the code with
>   ECHO ,

use [heredocs] style or print all HTML outside php tag:

1- [heredocs]

```
echo <<<HEREDOCS
any string here ' or "
HEREDOCS;
```

note: notations should be at beginning of each line and ends with line break without any space or indent.

2- separation logic

```
<?php
//here is php
//close php
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>This will also be ignored by PHP and displayed by the browser.</p> 
....
</body>
<?php
//php again
?>
```

Comment: about the separation logique , i know that but i don't want anything to show when the  user is not signed in i want it to be blank with only an error message like 404 NOT FOUND , nothing else  so the content of page will change depend on the user situation

Answer (score 0):

When you echo out code that uses both ' and  ", you escape the characters that match your opening and closing tags, like so:

```
echo '<p class="someclass">This can\'t be the end.</p>';
```

or

```
echo "<p class=\"someclass\">This can't be the end.</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the " & ' text parameter,you should just use text editor such as sublime to to replace all " to '

and for " in textarea you can replace with &#34;

then do

echo " <a href='#' value='{$var1}'>double quote mean &#34;</a>some other massive code ";

thus you can just use a <?php and ?> from the beginning of page till the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

What you can probably do is perform the check for the session variable at the start of the file and if the user is not logged in, use a header('Location: index.php'); followed by an exit();. If you do need to send headers based on logic that appears after the echo statements and changing the order of the statements is not doable, use output buffering.

Also, instead of including the HTML and Javascript within your code file, consider using a template engine, using include, or a combination of file_get_contents and echo (and possibly a string replace if you are using content placeholders). Heredocs and Nowdocs will make it easier to include single-quotes and double-quotes within strings.

Edit: If all you want to show unauthenticated users is an error message, you can redirect them to an error page, or use the PHP die(''); statement (which is like a combination of an echo and an exit).